# Differentiate an integral of two variables with respect to a function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

I have a known function of two variables $f = f(x_0,x)$, and another unknown function of one variable $w=w(x)$. They are related to each other by the equation:

\begin{equation}
L(x) = \int_{a}^{b} w(x_0) f(x_0,x) dx_0
\end{equation}

Where $a$ and $b$ are constants. What is the formula for $\frac{\partial L(x)}{\partial w(x)}$?

Comment: This seems more like [Calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) than functional analysis. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: Yes, I am. In fact, that's where this simplified version of my problem comes from. As far as I'm aware, the Euler Lagrange equation can't help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you have
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{ds}\bigg\vert_{s=0}L(w+sv)
&=\int_a^b\frac{d}{ds}\bigg\vert_{s=0}\big(w(x_0)+sv(x_0)\big)f(x_0,x)dx_0\\
&=\int_a^bv(x_0)f(x_0,x)dx_0
\end{align*}
as the directional derivative at $w$ in direction $v$.
The rest depends on your notation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to simplify this further? Or do you need to know more information about $f(x_0,x)$? In my case it can be written in this form: $f = e^{-kg(x_0,x)^2}$ where $k$ is a constant and $g$ is another function.

Comment: There is no nice simplification, at least not to my knowledge.

Comment: If it's true that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w} = 0$ then would it be true using the "fundamental lemma of Calculus of Variations" that $f(x_0,x) = 0$?

Comment: If you know that $f$ is continuous and that the space on which $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w}=0$ is large enough (for example $C_c^\infty$) then yes.